# Unknown exception: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__constant_time)

Tags: python, django, entity-framework, python-2.7, python-3.5

Dears ,

I'm trying to use paramiko with python3.5 installed at my MAC OS ELCAPATIN 10.11.4 from idle but still when i put the below script i face the below logs:

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect('x.x.x.x' , '22' , 'xxxxxx' , 'xxxxx')
```

but im facing the below traceback :

```
Unknown exception: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__constant_time)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__constant_time)
```